# Canon Camera ELPH 180 Continuous Power

Tags: canon, battery

I am using a Canon PowerShot ELPH 180 and am trying to take pictures with it for several days in a row using a script. This needs continuous power so the battery will not run out of power.

I could use something similar to [this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AE7K6LM). This battery outputs 4.2 volts but the actual camera uses a battery that outputs 3.6 volts.

Is this safe to use? What options do I have for continuous power? Do you know of any dummy batteries available for the ELPH 180?

Answer (score 3):

The ELPH 180 uses a NB-11L (or NB-11LH, basically the same) battery. So any adapter or DC coupler meant to power a NB-11L–type battery compartment should work.

Canon's [ACK-D90](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/ac-adapter-kit-ack-dc90) is the AC power adapter + DC coupler meant to power cameras that use an NB-11/L/LH battery. So any 3rd-party that is equivalent to it should work just fine.

Apparently, the DC coupler (the "dummy battery") part number is DR90 (or DR-90). I can't find it at Canon's site, but that's what many 3rd-party sellers seem to call it.

As far as using the product you show, if it were me, I would go with it. Battery-powered devices have voltage regulators precisely because the voltage output of batteries is never exactly what its label says. The labeled voltage is nominal. As the charge in a battery is depleted, its voltage drops. And that voltage drop profile is highly dependent upon on the battery's technology (alkaline, NiCad, NiMH, Li-ion, etc.). Bottom line, the camera will never rely on exactly 3.6V from the battery, so they much expect for and regulate varying input voltages.

---

Checking Canon's compatibility page for the ACK-D90, it only works with red ELPH 180's, or refurbished red or silver ELPH 180's. ;-)

(**Note**: I'm joking about the compatibility. That what Canon's site says, but clearly, the compatibility isn't depending on the color of the camera that otherwise is the same.)